# Get Json From Azure Storage Blob

Tags: json, azure, jsonp, azure-blob-storage

I want to get the json file in Azure Storage Blob through the browser.

I used Stream Analysis and comes out a json file in the Blob container. Now i need to get the information inside the json file in order to show the IOT device status in real-time.

I tried to use Jsonp, 
but I don't know how to add the callBack method in the Json file without download it. Is there any way to add the callBack method?? 
or Is there another way to get the information inside the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this particular scenario, I'd recommend PowerBI. Now Stream Analytics have direct output to PowerBI and you can pretty much customize the dashboard for your real time IoT needs.

You can refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard/) for step by step Stream Analytics + PowerBI.

Coming back to your question, you need to download the blob  to access the content. Stream Analytics to BLOB is usually for archiving or later predictive analysis scenarios.

Instead if you still prefer not to use PowerBI, I'd either arrange the SA output to an event hub and read the data from there in real time or alternatively save the data into a NO-SQL db like DocumentDB on Azure and then read from there. I can recommend [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) if you want to use custom gauges etc to visualize the data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'd like to use powerBI if there is a free one><.
After I get the Json file, i still need to do some working from the front-side. Can your solution do this as well??

Comment: Hi @HenryOu, Yes PowerBI is free till 10K rows/hr, you can find the details [link](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/pricing). SA can have multiple outputs at the same time, so you may consider configuring one for PowerBI for realtime showcase and the second one for Event Hubs. Once you have the data in EH which essentially a massively scalable queue structure, you can use the SDKs for different platforms to pull the data from it. Therefore you can implement anything you want in your  Java/C# etc...code. Detailed info about it is [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn789972.aspx)

Comment: Glad it helped, can you kindly check it as an answer if this answers your question? So that other people can also benefit from it. Thanks